# Creating a class and custom objects(or types?) to use when instantiating

Tags: vb.net, class, enums

I need to create a class. A rather simple one. We'll call the class `clsItem`, just for the purposes of this question. The values this class has to hold are:

- `PointX` - some X coord for a point
- `PointY` - some Y coord for a point
- `Type` - This would be one of several options (e.g. Computer, Printer, Router, Server)

I'm a little comfortable with creating a class, properties, get/set, and so on just for straightforward values. However, when creating an instance of this class, and filling out the parameters for a new instance, I would like enumerated options to appear (I think I'm looking for enumerations at least).

An instance will ask for (as above)  (X coord, Y coord, Type)

```
Dim NewClass As New clsItem(50, 75, Type.Computer)**
```

Or `Type.Printer`, `Type.Router`....

The actual values of `Type.[whatever]` can just be a number, I suppose (0,1,2....).  But how do I go about setting this up so as I'm actually writing this class I can make a Property that's using this?

There's `Dim something As Integer`, or `As String`. So I think I would need 
`Dim something As HardwareType` (or whatever I will name it).

```
Public Property Type As HardwareType
```

Would creating a Structure in this class work? Or is there a better way?

**EDIT 1**

```
Public Class clsItem

    Public Property PointX As Integer
    Public Property PointY As Integer

    Public Property ItemType As Integer


    Sub New(X As Integer, Y As Integer, Type As Integer)
        PointX = X
        PointY = Y
        ItemType = Type
    End Sub

End Class
```

I guess the above could be one way to do this as this only has a to be a rather simple class.

But what I want passed as `Type` in `Sub New`, are things like

```
Type.Computer
Type.Printer
Type.Switch
Type.Router
```

So an Integer may not be what I actually want. I need to create `Type.[something]` and set a value to each so I can then iterate through `Type` in my program when I want to instance this class.

Comment: fair question, but you'd be better off providing some code for the hypothetical class and how you use rather than narrative.

Comment: define `ItemType` as an enum such as Steven Doggart suggests and pass that in the ctor, too

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a constructor.  The constructor is like a method which is always called each time an object of the class is created.  If the constructor has parameters, then you must pass arguments to those parameters when you create the object (e.g. `New Item(50, 75, HardwareType.Computer)`)  The name of the constructor in the class is always `New`:

```
Public Class Item
    Public Sub New(x As Integer, y As Integer, t As HardwareType)
        Me.X = x
        Me.Y = y
        Me.Type = t
    End Sub

    Public Property X As Integer
    Public Property Y As Integer
    Public Property [Type] As HardwareType
End Class
```

To provide a defined list of constant option for a parameter, you need to declare it as an `Enum`:

```
Public Enum HardwareType
    Computer
    Printer
    Switch
    Router
End Enum
```